# How Set a property table if table is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need SET a property of a table Blt_Boleta.ti_Pk_IdEstadoRevision = 3, if #tablaTemporal = null. I was thinking make this between the Insert and FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @boletaActual. Maybe with a Count or somethig like this...

So how can I do this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[paBltBuscarBoletasASA] @id_Asa int  
      -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
DECLARE @boletaActual int
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal 
(
Numero_Pregunta varchar(250), 
Numero_Boleta char(8), 
Cultivo varchar(250), 
Numero_Siembra int, 
Detalle_Error varchar(250)
)
DECLARE miCursor CURSOR FOR

                SELECT 
                    localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
                FROM 
                    Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
                WHERE 
                    boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND
                    localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa
OPEN miCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @boletaActual

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal
(Numero_Pregunta, Numero_Boleta, Cultivo, Numero_Siembra, Detalle_Error)  
exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @boletaActual

FETCH NEXT FROM miCursor INTO @boletaActual
END

CLOSE miCursor
DEALLOCATE miCursor
SELECT * FROM #tablaTemporal
```

Comment: Do you want to update `Blt_boleta` if the table, `#tableTemporal` does not exist, or if some value inside of it does not?  SQL Server should have an 'information schema' (most other RDBMSs I know of do), which has information about tables/columns/etc, in a set of tables.  I don't happen to know what yours are, and I'm a bit afraid that temporary tables aren't referenced there.  If you just want to update based on the existence of a row, it's trivial (one statment, usually).  If based on the table's existence, you _may_ be able to do that in a stored procedure, if you can check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check whether `#tableTemporal` is null because it will never be. You probably meant to check if there are rows inserted into #tableTemporal after you exec `paBltMarcarErroresBoleta`.

If I understood correctly, I think you could do after `exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @boletaActual` something like:

```
DECLARE miCursor CURSOR FOR

                SELECT 
                    localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
                FROM 
                    Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
                WHERE 
                    boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND
                    localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa
FOR UPDATE OF Blt_Boleta.ti_Pk_IdEstadoRevision
```

And after `exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @boletaActual`

```
if not exists(select 1 from #tableTemporal)
 update Blt_Boleta
 set Blt_Boleta.ti_Pk_IdEstadoRevision=3 
 where current of miCursor
```

But you can probably execute this better with a simple while loop instead of the cursor.